# jQuery conflict with body onload event

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a function `onBodyLoad` that called from body `onload`:

```
var someGlobalVar = new SpecialType();

function onBodyLoad() {
  someGlobalVar.Bind();
}
```

When I include **jQuery 1.4.2** in my project I got an error that someGlobalVar is **undefined**.
Why JQuery is affecting global variable?
Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a side note.

```
// DOM Ready
$(document).ready(function() {});

// When the page has completely loaded
<body onload="someFunction()">
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you need to use `<body onload='OnBodyLoad()'>` anymore, you can change thise to use jQuery's `document.ready` (and move it to an external file!) like this:

```
var someGlobalVar=new SpecialType(); 
$(OnBodyLoad);
//or..
$(function() {
  //other stuff..
  OnBodyLoad();
});
//or...
$(document).ready(function() {
  //other stuff..
  OnBodyLoad();
});
```

Comment: @Sean - It does if the `onload` handler is getting overridden or changed in any way, attaching a handler in this method would resolve that....this is *far* more likely than jQuery interfering with his object.

Comment: But why would including jQuery do such a thing? But I know what your'e getting at.

Comment: @Sean - It wouldn't out of the box, but I doubt the poster has simply added jQuery, probably either creates a javascript error overall, or there actually is some code the OP is running and the question isn't complete, which is the more common case on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use jQuery's load event?

```
$(window).load(function() {
      functiontoexecute();
});
```

It is simple, and it is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps jQuery interferes with `SpecialType` and so the call to `new SpecialType();` results in the variable someGlobalVar being `undefined`.

Try using the console to check for any warnings, and try to instantiate a SpecialType object manually. This should give you some insight.